# How to get the output of a function in db-connect file to another file which includes a html table?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm not much familiar with PHP.

I want to write the table tags in html, inside the abc.php file without designing it inside db_connect file using php tags.

The file(abc) which I have calling the function in db_connect file.

```
<?php


include('a_header.php');
include_once('classes/class.database.php');
    $db = new db();
    ?>

<div id="table1 >

    <?php
    echo "<table border='1' width='300px' >
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>";

    ?>

</div>


        <?php
    $res2 = $db->get_patients();


include('a_footer.php');?>
```

This is the function I have written inside the db_connect file.

```
<?php
class db{     

function get_patients($name=NULL,$email=NULL,$username='gayani'){
            $query2 = "select distinct a.name, a.email from patient a,doctor_patient b, doctor c where c.username='".$username."' and c.username=b.doc_name and b.serial_no=a.serial_no" ;
                    . "  and name='".$name."';";

        $res2 = mysql_query($query2,$this->con);

            while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($res2)){
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td> <a href='v_patient.php'/>" . $row2['name'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row2['email'] . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";      
        }

            echo "</table>";
    }
```

I want to write the table tags in html, inside the abc.php file without designing it inside db_connect file using php tags. I tried it. But its not working. Help me guys.

Comment: Define "it's not working".

Comment: Are you actually opening a database connection?

Comment: yes. db connection is okay. not working means,  I wrote the table in html tags inside the db_connect file. Then the output data of the query is not displayed. I want the html code only in abc.php file and get the data passing from db_connect file at there.

Comment: why u dont want html tags in abc.php?

Comment: nope. that's not what I mean. I want html tags in abc.php file. But I couldn't come up with that. Because of that I had to placed html tags inside db_connect file. Can anybody tell me how to do it?